# compare cells in Excel and show the faulty rows in red with C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am trying to compare the date in a row of an Excel sheet. As an example a screenshot from the Excel:

[image: 1]

In line 20 of the example I want to compare the date and if something like that appears in the line, i.e. between the 12/22/2020 and the 12/29/20, then the line should be marked red. So all lines where an anomaly occurs.

I hope you know what I mean.

Here is my code:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ReadExcelAndFilterData
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", Multiselect = false})
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(ofd.FileName))
                {
                    bool isFirstRow = true;
                    var rows = workbook.Worksheet(1).RowsUsed();
                    foreach(var row in rows)
                    {
                        if (isFirstRow)
                        {
                            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                                dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                            isFirstRow = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add();
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i++] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    dataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    lblTotal.Text = $"Total records: {dataGridView.RowCount}";
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataView dv = dataGridView.DataSource as DataView;
            if (dv != null)
                dv.RowFilter = txtSearch.Text;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            btnSearch.PerformClick();
    }
 }
}
```

This is how the result currently looks:

[image: 2]

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance

Update 02.12.2020

[image: 3]

Comment: *if something like that appears* - this is what isn't really clear. You want to compare *which date* with *what*, and mark the line if the result is *what*?

Comment: Once you've defined this, you can do `dt.Rows[index].RowError = "your explanation message";`

Comment: Hello Rafalon, 
thank you for the answer.The date in a line should always be in ascending order as this is the best before date. As shown in the screenshot the correct date is not always delivered. 
Now I would like to show these lines in which the date is not in ascending order in red.
Sorry, it is really hard to describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this:

```
DateTime? previousDate = null;
bool isAscending = true;
foreach (var cell in row.Cells())
{
    // set the value in DataTable
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i++] = cell.Value.ToString();
    
    // check needs to be done if previous checks were successful and current value is a DateTime
    if (isAscending && cell.Value is DateTime currentDate)
    {
        if (previousDate == null || previousDate <= currentDate)
        {
            previousDate = currentDate;
        }
        else
        {
            isAscending = false;
        }
    }
}
if (!isAscending)
{
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1].RowError = "Dates are not in ascending order";
}
```

I wrote it in a way that I believe is self-explanatory, but in case it isn't clear enough feel free to ask for clarifications

The `RowError` property will show a red mark like this, and the text you set will be in a tooltip on hover:
[image: RowError]

Comment: Thanks for your help and the code, but I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find the error. Added a new screenshot to my question.

Comment: @Legion Your `bool isAscending = true;` should be **inside** the first `foreach` loop (with your current code, once you find a faulty row, you never set it back to `true`, so it stays `false` until the end)

Comment: Also note that the part `|| currentDate == null` can never occur, as `currentDate` is a `DateTime` (non-nullable) so it isn't actually needed. EDIT: you also need to set `previousDate` to null **inside** the first `foreach` loop (along `isAscending`)